# Protobuf as a data type and conversion to struct

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-spanner

Could we use a protobuf to store a complex value in a column in cloud spanner and convert it (hopefully automatically :-)  ) to a struct when retrieving it?

We know we can have struct as a datatype but this might be a feasible workaround.

Comment: This is the relevant feature request: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/203849138

Answer (score 1):

Protobufs are not supported at the moment. I think we can store them as BYTES and do the (un)marshaling at client.

I don't think Protobuf to Struct conversion is supported. Can you elaborate your use case?